# Java jax-rs response - Java EE return list

Tags: java, java-ee, rest, jax-rs

Не могу разобраться с java jax-rs response.
Есть вот такой вот код:

```
public class OrderRestImpl implements OrderRest {

@Inject
private DaoManager daoManager;

@Override
public Response findByNameAndId(String name, Long id) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Hello, the name is: " + name + " Your table \n\n");
    List<String> result = daoManager.handleRequest(name, id);
    for (String s : result) {
        sb.append(s).append('\n');
    }


    Response theBestResponseIveEverMade = Response.ok(result).type("text/plain").build();
    return theBestResponseIveEverMade;
//        return Response.status(Response.Status.theBestResponseIveEverMade).entity("new").type("text/plain").build();
}
```

Этот метод вызывается в сервлете прямо из `pw.println(orderRestImpl.findByNameAndId(name, num));`
Это позволяет сразу же вывести на экран строку вида

```
OutboundJaxrsResponse{status=200, reason=OK, hasEntity=true, closed=false, buffered=false}
```

Это все хорошо, но как мне вывести всю информацию, которую я насобирал в список result?
Спасибо всем)

Comment: так позовите `response.getEntity()`

Comment: но есть ощущение, что вы что-то не то делаете.

Comment: Это вызвать и сохранить куда нибудь и в  return потом?